# Error while launching Flutter app on iOS emulator: "Error retrieving thread information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port"

Tags: ios, flutter

On macOS Big Sur (Macbook Air with M1 chipset), I installed Android Studio and the Flutter and Dart plugins.

I created a brand new Flutter project with nothing in it, and just launched it on an iPhone emulator. It works fine, but I have the following log that appears multiple times per second:

```
[VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios_mm(184)] Error retrieving thread information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

It looks like it's a known bug, but I can't find any fix for that.

Does anyone knows how to get rid of that log?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like problem with the M1 chipset and macos version...? Firstly maybe try to turn on verbose logging to dig into details. secondly maybe use wireshark to look at those ports?

Comment: I tried `flutter doctor -v` but I got nothing interesting. Also, it seems that it's a problem that existed before the M1 chipset.

Comment: maybe flutter run -v? since doctor only detect env issues

Comment: Please has anyone been able to solve this issue? I'm seeing same error and my app is not even launching

Comment: This does appear on M1 AND on Intel Macs ... I had to revert to my old machine after many more issues on M1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to Flutter 2 by doing `flutter upgrade` solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

This issue is related to the new MacBook with M1 processor with flutter 1 just try to run the app with this command will help running the app in Flutter #1

```
flutter run | grep -v "Error retrieving thread information"
```

or you can use the command below to upgrade to Flutter #2 and fix the problem

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: for the time bing this is perfect :)